# How to revoke a slack token?

Tags: curl, slack, slack-api

I know about the slack API auth.revoke, but when I use it, it doesn't work.

I am trying the following by inputting it in my terminal, where `<TOKEN>` is the slack token.

`curl -i https://slack.com/api/auth.revoke H "Authorization: Bearer <TOKEN>"`

The error that I am getting is:

```
{"ok":false,"error":"not_authed"}curl: (6) Could not resolve host: H
curl: (3) Port number ended with ' '
```

I am expecting to see, `{"ok":true,"revoked":true}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get this response because you technically did not provide a token to the API method. Providing tokens in an authorization header only works with methods that support a POST body in JSON.  [`auth.revoke`](https://api.slack.com/methods/auth.revoke) does not support that as it's stated in the official documentation:

> Present arguments as parameters in `application/x-www-form-urlencoded querystring` or POST body. This method does not currently accept `application/json`.

Here is the correct syntax with curl:

```
curl https://slack.com/api/auth.revoke -X POST --data "token=TOKEN"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the slack CLI to revoke a token:

```bash
$ slack auth revoke
? Enter a token to revoke ******************************************
️  Authorization successfully revoked
   Login to a new team with slack login
   Create a new token with slack auth token

$
```